How to merge duplicate ubuntu directory?
I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04 on / root directory because of a faulty update. I have two partition / for the OS and /home for data. After the re-installation, I found out that all my data at /home/Downloads are gone but they still exist at /home/user/Downloads. Is there a way to merge the two directory? I have new files in /home and old files in /home/user




Copy all files into the Downloads directory you wish to keep. Then delete the directory you don't want to keep and replace it with a symlink called "Downloads", which point to the right directory. If a program tries to download into the wrong directory, the file will be written in the right one.
